# Lower bound for the function $f(x) = x\sin x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, upper-lower-bounds

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(x)=x\sin x.$$
If $x$ is sufficiently large, I mean $R>0$ sufficiently large exists such that $x$ is in the complementar of the ball $B(0, R)$, it is possible to have a lower bound for the function $f$?

Actually I think to the limit for $x\to +\infty$ fo that function which is indeterminate, so I think that it is not possible to find a lower bound, but I am not sure about that.

${\bf EDIT:}$ So, in articular, it is possible or not to have a lower bound for the integral
$$\int_0^T f(x) dx,$$
with $T>0$, isn't it?

Could someone please help me with that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $f(\frac {3\pi } 2 +2n\pi) \to -\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: No, $f$ is unbounded in both directions: $\sup\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)=\infty$ and $\inf\limits_{x\in\Bbb{R}}f(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: "Actually I think to the limit for $x\to +\infty$ fo that function which is indeterminate, so I think that it is not possible to find a lower bound". You should have a look to the graph of this function, to see why it has no lower bound. It can help you to solve similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following sequences, where $k$ goes to infinity.

$$f(\pi/2 + k2\pi) = \pi/2 + k2\pi \rightarrow +\infty$$

$$f(-\pi/2 + k2\pi) = \pi/2 - k2\pi \rightarrow -\infty$$

You can compute the integral explicitely with an integration by part.

$$ \int_0^T x \sin(x) dx = [-x \cos(x)]_0^T - \int_0^T \cos(x) dx = 
-T \cos(T) +\sin(T).$$

Here again you can find sequences for which this last quantity goes to $-\infty$ or $+\infty$.

Comment: coudy, so it can be found neither a lower bound nor an upper bound for the iintegral, isn't it?

Comment: You are correct. There is no lower bound nor upper bound for the integral.